# Run the script with screen

Tags: scripts, screen, init.d

I write a script to run p2pool. I can not understand how to add a run through the "screen -dmS"?

> ```
>    #! /bin/sh
>    ### BEGIN INIT INFO
>    # Provides:          p2pool start
>    # Required-Start:    $all
>    # Required-Stop:     $remote_fs
>    # Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
>    # Default-Stop:      0 1 6
>    # Short-Description: Auto init p2pool start
>    # Description:       Auto init p2pool start via booting system
>    #                    placed in /etc/init.d.
>    ### END INIT INFO
>    # Author: Foo Bar <foobar@baz.org>
>    #
>    # Please remove the "Author" lines above and replace them
>    # with your own name if you copy and modify this script.
>    # Do NOT "set -e"
>    # PATH should only include /usr/* if it runs after the mountnfs.sh script
>    PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
>    DESC="P2Pool Start"
>    NAME=python
>    DAEMON=/usr/bin/$NAME
>    DAEMON_ARGS="/home/wzor/p2pool/run_p2pool.py --net bitcoin --give-author 0 rpcuser rpcpass -a bitwallet -d A --max-conns 100 --outgoing-conns 10 --fee 0"
>    DAEMON_LOADER="/usr/bin/taskset 0x8 "$DAEMON
>    PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid
>    SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME
>    CHUID=user:user
>    # Exit if the package is not installed
>    [ -x "$DAEMON" ] || exit 0
>    # Read configuration variable file if it is present
>    [ -r /etc/default/$NAME ] && . /etc/default/$NAME
>    # Load the VERBOSE setting and other rcS variables
>    . /lib/init/vars.sh
>    # Define LSB log_* functions.
>    # Depend on lsb-base (>= 3.2-14) to ensure that this file is present
>    # and status_of_proc is working.
>    . /lib/lsb/init-functions
>    #
>    # Function that starts the daemon/service
>    #
>    do_start()
>    {
>    # Return
>    #   0 if daemon has been started
>    #   1 if daemon was already running
>    #   2 if daemon could not be started
>    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON_LOADER --test > /dev/null \
>     || return 1
>    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --chuid $CHUID --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec    $DAEMON_LOADER -- \
>     $DAEMON_ARGS \
>     || return 2
>    # Add code here, if necessary, that waits for the process to be ready
>    # to handle requests from services started subsequently which depend
>    # on this one.  As a last resort, sleep for some time.
>    }
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're asking:

You need to run `screen -dmS (somenamegoeshere) -X (pathtoscript)` and replace `(somenamegoeshere)` with a unique name to identify it and `(pathtoscript)` with the path to your script.